# What is needed to keep datalogging alive in a Cordova phone app

Tags: cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a Cordova app, which shows data from a my custom BLE sensor and also logs the data into a file in app sandbox.

What is needed for the app to keep logging data to file while the phone is locked. I have noticed that the app keeps logging the whole night, if the phone is connected to the charger. The data is logged then at 250 ms intervals as it should (each notification from the sensor). This is tested with Android (Galaxy S8) and IPad.

If S8 is not connected to a charger, the app is killed at some point. Maybe depending on battery level?

At the moment I'm not using anything to keep the app alive, no background plugins, no services, no whitelisting, no wakelocks etc. Just ble and file plugins.

What's the recommended way to make sure the app logs as long as the battery is alive or the user stops the app or logging inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from when BLE scanning with a pending intent, your BLE connection will be alive as long as your app process is alive (and the app itself maintains a connection). That means there is nothing BLE specific in your question actually. So your question is really how to make the app process stay alive.

The only "documented" solution is to simply have a Foreground Service, which will make sure your app process stays alive and the system doesn't kill it randomly. On many Huawei phones however, the app must also be whitelisted by the user in the Phone settings so that it isn't killed, since for some reason Huawei thought it was a good idea to randomly kill apps running a Foreground Service.

Comment: Is it enough just to use cordova-plugin-foreground-service and its start function? Or do I need something more like a background plugin? I'm a bit confused about background and foreground. Since my application works with charger I guess it's not running in the backround although screen is locked and other apps where used.

Comment: I just updated S8 to Android Pie and now the app was killed even with the charger. I haven't tried using foreground service yet. It needs a permission in Pie. Is there a good tutorial or an example of an app that keeps alive?

Comment: I tried to add cordova-plugin-foreground-service, but the app hangs when I call cordova.plugins.foregroundService.start('GPS Running', 'Background Service'); I had addded  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The reason cordova-plugin-foreground-service is not working is that Phonegap Build skips it during build due to version problem. This plugin requires cordova version >=8.0.0. I'm using CLI-8.1.1 version of Phonegap build, but it says cordova 7.10: "Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 7.1.0, failed version requirement: >=8.0.0". Is cordova version something different than CLI version or is there a bug somewhere?